# How do I know that content of a USB drive is changed or not

Tags: usb, fat32

I am writing an embedded system multimedia application where support to play from USB drive is there. Generally when a USB drive is inserted, the application parses the entire USB drive to list all songs and videos present in the drive. This list is stored in a database. In case the same drive is connected later, the application uses the list from the database.

Identification of the drive is done using the serial number from the USB device descriptor. But the problem is how do I detect that any new content is added or any existing content is deleted?
Currently I am targeting for supporting FAT32 formatted USB drives only.

Is there any way to detect the change in the content of the drive? Like last accessed time-stamp or last modified cluster?

Comment: Since serial numbers are not always present, you might consider always reloading the contents of the device.  Then, changed content isn't an issue.  I suspect you would have to read through the FAT/directories anyway.

Comment: But in case of huge folder structure present in the media, reloading the content may take very large amount of time. That's why I was looking for any mechanism to detect any change in the media

Comment: you can keep a list of file names and timestamps in your cache database.  You only need to reload that content that changes.  Parsing directories on the device will be relatively fast, except in extreme cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got access to the raw block device, you could cache the relevant parts of the [FS information sector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FS_Information_Sector).  Either the number of free clusters or the number of the most recently allocated cluster changing will tell you that *something* changed, although you'd have to track down what that was manually. The last modified entry in the directory table *might* be useful for this, but I don't think it's necessarily reliable - that depends on how stringent whatever wrote to the device was.